# asp setting variable depending on dropdown list and passing it to a button click event

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

So this is a little hard to explain what I am trying to achieve but hopefully, you can grasp the idea from my code. I have a dropdown and need the code to set a variable to either true or false depending on the dropdown value. Now I have this working OK. But when I call the variable containing the true or false, it is always false when called from a button on click event. Even when the variable is set to true if I change the dropdown selection.

I don't know if that makes sense to others but here is my HTML code for the dropdown.

```
<div class="col-2 text-right form-group">
                <p align="center">Technician Selection</p>
                <asp:DropDownList id="TeckSel" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="TeckSel_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" Width="100%">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Select Technician" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Michael" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Calvin" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Ben" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Haydon" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Luke" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Liam" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
```

And here is my c# to go with that.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    String TechName = "";
    String TeckKey = "";
    bool Selected;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void TeckSel_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var DropList = TeckSel.SelectedValue;

    switch (DropList)
    {
        case "-1":
            Selected = false;
            TechName = "Calvin Reid";
            break;
        case "1":
            TeckKey = "emememe";
            TechName = "Dave";
            Selected = true;
            break;
        case "2":
            TeckKey = "emememe";
            TechName = "Steve";
            Selected = true;
            break;
    }
    ActionOutput.Text = TechName + Selected.ToString();
}



protected void ButUnlockAcc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ActionOutput.Text = Selected.ToString() + TechName.ToString();

}
}
```

I should note I have a text box called 'ActionOutput' and also a button with the onclick event called 'ButUnlockAcc_click'.

Any help as to why when the button is pressed the value of the bool called 'Selected' is always false even if stated in the switch that its true would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to call the `TeckSel_SelectedIndexChanged` to set the value of `Selected` upon button click:

```
protected void ButUnlockAcc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TeckSel_SelectedIndexChanged(sender,e);
    ActionOutput.Text = Selected.ToString() + TechName.ToString();
}
```

Comment: were you able to achieve the desired outcome? @calv

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate more on this? I do think that would work however none of my variables which I set in the case statement seem to be correct when I click the button. I.E the selected value is always false and TechName is always empty.

Comment: never mind I actually didn't read your answer correctly at first. But now understand what you mean. I've changed my code and it works as expected, thank you very much!